# Load multiple templates TWIG in one PHP file

Tags: php, twig

I installed TWIG in my project written on pure PHP and I would like to create an array to load many `*.twig` pages  or use `$_GET['page']`.

Is it possible?

This is my code :

```
<?php
    include('twig.php');
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('testmacro.twig');
    echo $template->render(array()); 
?>
```

This code loads only one `*.twig` page

Thanks in advance

Comment: why tag this as `symfony2` if it is not using symfony?

Comment: To have more views ;)

Comment: You should use a main base template and include the necessary files in there

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just load 2 templates and call the echo function twice :

```
<?php
    include('twig.php');
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('testmacro.twig');
    echo $template->render(array()); 
    $template2 = $twig->loadTemplate('testmacro2.twig');
    echo $template2->render(array()); 
?>
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Comment: Sometimes there is not much to say :)

Comment: But OK, I added some explainations ;)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah it just popped up in the review queue.